# Multiple thread with multiple table insert

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, hibernate, transactions

I am working on Spring+Hibernate based web application.
In this application I have to do calculation on 50000 records available into the database.
Current logic :-

1. Loop through 0 to 50000 (All 50000 records are independent to each other)
2. Select ith element
3. Do calculation on ith element (Drop **CALCULATION_TEMP** table if exist, create new table **CALCULATION_TEMP** and insert calculation in **CALCULATION_TEMP** table)
4. Do some calculation on step 3 table and get the result
5. Put step 4 result into **Results** table

***Currently these all calculation taking around 38 hours to complete with single thread.***

Now we want to run this system by multiple threads.
For testing purpose I have taken 50 records.

*Using Single thread it is taking around **30 sec**.*

*Using two threads :-*

- Half records performing by first thread and rest of the records by second thread.
- Now I am using two TEMP tables for both threads. (TEMP1 and TEMP2)
- It is taking **225 sec**.

Rough Code :-

```
for (int i = 0; i < recordsSize; i++) {
    final int j = i;
    String recordId = list.get(i);

    // Method call : Code for creating CALCULATION_TEMP table
    // CALCULATION_TEMP table will contain dynamic number of column. It is depends on the record data (50 to 70 columns)
    // return flag value
    boolean flag = xyzMethod(....);

    if (flag) {

        // All calculation done in this method 
        // Around 600 - 700 rows will be created into CALCULATION_TEMP table on the basis of calculation logic
        Object fileMapColumnData[] = /* Method call */;

        // Insert result for one record into RESULT table for unique recordId (this result is calculated in CALCULATION_TEMP table)  
        insertIntoResultTable(....);

        // Drop CALCULATION_TEMP table
    } else {
        LOGGER.error("Unable to calculate ... because of some wrong data");
        loggerDTO.getCustomLogger().severe("Unable to calculate ... because of some wrong data");
    }
    if (i % 100 == 0) {
        calculationDao.flushAndClear();
    }

    // Thread for showing process completion status in percentage
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getPercentageDone((float) recordsSize, (float) (j + 1));
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

Please suggest, How I can improve the performance.

Comment: Can you not use the same temp table with different keys? Also, are you sure you cannot achieve this calculation by a simple procedure in DB?

Comment: Its more of a DB side work as @aksappy mentioned than Java side..

Comment: One temp table refers to one result. So we can't use same temp table. According to client requirement we can't use Stored Procedure,

Comment: I don't have an idea about your calculation. How about calculate your element by using like SQL GROUP or COUNT function?

Comment: Calculation is very complex. I need to do calculation for every month. Like for one record I have 20 year data. So 20*12 = 240 rows will be created with dynamic number of column (around 50 to 70 )with each record . That's why I need to recreate the table for each record.

Comment: How do you get the connection to the database? What kind of machine(cpu cores, ram) are you running the code in development and will be running in Production?

Comment: This is my development machine. But Same issue is coming on Production also. That's why we are now working on performance. Using datasource for db connection. 
<Resource name="jdbc/TEST_CALC"
         auth="Container"
         type="javax.sql.DataSource"
         driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
         url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/calc_test"
         username="root"
         password="root"
         removeAbandoned="true"
         removeAbandonedTimeout="90"
         logAbandoned="true"
         maxActive="100"
         maxIdle="10"
         maxWait="-1"/>

Answer (score 0):

Creating/Droping temporary tables take a lots of time by 50000 times. Can you do calculations without temporary table ? It can improve peformance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hard and fast rule for performance improvements. If you are having constraints and business decisions, we need to know the calculations and how the threads are managed, connections are managed and the number of loops involved etc. There are so many things to consider. Start with checking the pain point areas, the time taken for it and improve each method first.

Comment: Threads behave the way you have coded it. Without seeing the code, I can only imagine your thread waiting for something to complete a.k.a locks. Moreover, is your connection busy? What kind of queries are being used? As I said, there is no single answer.

Comment: @RahulJain - Is the whole program execution taking 225 seconds, including table creations and querying etc? or is it just your calculation logic on 25 records?

Comment: It is only for 50 records. 
By using single thread it is taking 30 sec but for two threads it is taking around 225 sec.

Comment: @RahulJain.. the performance after increasing the no of threads depends on the machine you are running the code.

Comment: Using 4GB RAM on development with Core 2 DUO processor.

Comment: Share the code snippets as much as possible please! ;)